# Spark reading parquet files from HDFS partition path failing to load value of partition in SELECT query but fetching right data using partition filter

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, parquet

I'm having data at different hadoop cluster

Table name: table_name

Partitions: partition1, partition2, partition3

Sample HDFS data paths:

hdfs://namenodename.cluster.com/data/table_name/partition1=IN/partition2=20220430/partition3=DEF/partition4=FE

```
hdfs://namenodename.cluster.com/data/table_name/partition1=IN/partition2=20220430/partition3=BUC/partition4=TE
```

I have spark code which runs below query using spark.sql and writes to output table 'output_table'

```
spark.sql("select column1, column2, column3, partition3 from parquet.`hdfs://namenodename.cluster.com/data/table_name/partition1=IN/partition2=20220430` 
where partition3='DEF' and partition4='FE'")
```

And then writes to a table `output_table`.

In above query "partition3='DEF' and partition4='FE'" filter is being applied properly but `output_table` has `column, partition3` null for all data.

I'm facing above in PROD only. In UAT I couldn't replicate the issue; it's working properly.

I used parquet-tools to check the variance between source data from PROD and UAT. But I'm having issue with partition column, the details of it are not stored in parquet files.

Update: When I compared the logs between PROD and UAT: I got a warning:
datasources.Datasource: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema and the partition schema: `partition4`, `partition3`;

I brought the part files of below partition from PROD and in UAT I'm not getting that warning.

```
   hdfs://namenodename.cluster.com/data/table_name/partition1=IN/partition2=20220430/partition3=DEF/partition4=FE
```